# Jsonata, merging array of objects

Tags: jsonata

I have an array of objects that I would like to reformat using a jsonata expression

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "time": 1575417919282,
            "message": {
                "data": 21,
                "type": "temperature"
            }

        },
        {
            "time": 1575417919282,
            "message": {
                "data": 45,
                "type": "temperature"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

Desired format

```
[
    {
        "data": 21,
        "type": "temperature",
        "time": 1575417919282
    },
    {
        "data": 45,
        "type": "temperature"
        "time": 1575417919282
    }
]
```

Is there an easy one liner for this? I started with merging time into the message object using `$merge([$.items.message, {"time":$.items.time}])` but his gives me

```
{
  "data": 45,
  "type": "temperature",
  "time": [
    1575417919282,
    1575417919282
  ]
}
```

I'm finding the documentation hard to follow. How do you start with just merging two objects iteratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
items.{
   "data": message.data,
   "type": message.type,
   "time": time
}
```

http://try.jsonata.org/SJZDsyHTr

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I guess I don't understand the usecase for `$merge`