# Turn a JSON array of key/value pairs into object properties

Tags: jsonata

I'm trying to use JSONata to convert arrays of "key/value" objects into properties of the parent object. My input looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "city": "Ottawa",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "population",
        "value": 37
      },
      {
        "name": "postalCode",
        "value": 10001
      },
      {
        "name": "founded",
        "value": 1826
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "Toronto",
    "properties": [
      {
        "name": "population",
        "value": 54
      },
      {
        "name": "postalCode",
        "value": 10002
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm struggling to generate the output I need, I've seen examples that reference explicit elements, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171614/13114951), but I need the properties to be converted "dynamically" since I don't know them in advance. I think I need something like this, but I'm missing some particular function:

```js
$[].{
    "city": city,
    properties.name: properties.value
}
```

This is the output I need to generate:

```json
[
  {
    "city": "Ottawa",
    "population": 37,
    "postalCode": 10001,
    "founded": 1826
  },
  {
    "city": "Toronto",
    "population": 54,
    "postalCode": 10002
  }
]
```

The `properties` arrays don't always contain the same keys, but the `city` attributes are always present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [reduce operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#---reduce), as described in the Grouping docs [here](https://docs.jsonata.org/sorting-grouping#grouping):

```
$[].(
  $city := city;
  properties{ "city": $city, name: value }   
)
```

You can play with it live: https://stedi.link/uUANwtE

Comment: how to do this one in PHP? Any ideas or resources?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this expression.

```
 $[].{
    "city": $.city,
    $.properties[0].name: $.properties[0].value,
    $.properties[1].name: $.properties[1].value,
    $.properties[2].name: $.properties[2].value,
    $.properties[3].name: $.properties[3].value
}
```

https://try.jsonata.org/s1Ea4kUvo

Comment: I don't think this solution is complete, as the author said that the properties are not known in advance, so they can't be sure that there would be only 4 of them each time.

Comment: If you know the maximum number of fields that can come in a field you can use this. It does not throw any null or undefined errors.